# How to append string columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to append string based on values in other table.

DF1:

```
s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6
-----------------
 1  1  1  0  1  1
```

Same way Df2 is like

Df2:

```
Tech_ID  Std_Id  s1_Norm  s2 Norm  S3 Norm  S4_Norm  S5 Norm  S6_Norm
----------------------------------------------------
   1        1       11        01       10       11       00       01
   1        7       01        11       01       11       01       10
   2        4       00        10       00       11       10       11
   3        8       10        11       01       01       11       00
.
.
.      ​
```

Now want to generate the string  based on DF1 Values

For 1st row.
s1+s1_Norm+s2+s2_Norm+s3+s3_Norm+s5+s5_Norm+s6+s6_Norm

s4 and s4_norm are not taken in string calculation as s4 value is 0.

Same way any S series value 0 then value of that s bit and s_Norm bit not considered in string generation.

Expected result:

```
Tech_ID  Std_Id      Result
---------------------------------
  1        1      111101110100101
  1        7      101111101101110
  2        4      100110100110111
  3        8      100111101111100
.
.
.
```

Same way if s4= 1 and s3=0 then s3 and s3_Norm should not consider in string generation.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate `df1` to `df2` as strings, then use matrix multiplication `@`:

```
(df1.astype(str).values + df2) @ df1.T.values
```

Output:

```
                 0
0  111101110100101
1  101111101101110
2  100110100110111
```

Comment: `@` works here because in `pandas` string columns are object dtype, with python string elements.  `'astring*0' produces `''`.  And `+ for strings is concatente.  Matrix multiplication is a "sum-of-products" action, normally defined just for numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add two columns in DB2, which represent the string status values of it, 
I updated DF2 in question please check.

Comment: @NiravPrajapati just select the columns you need, replace `df2` with `df2.iloc[:,2:]`...

Answer (score 0):

Quang Hoang's matrix multiplication is really impressive. It also possible to use `apply()` with [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress). `itertools.compress(data, selectors)` is used to filter elements from data where corresponding element in selectors that evaluates to `False`.

```py
import itertools

d_ = (df1.astype(str).values + df2.iloc[:,2:]).apply(lambda row: ''.join(itertools.compress(row.tolist(), df1.loc[0].tolist())), axis=1)

df_ = pd.concat([df2.iloc[:, :2], d_], axis=1)
```

```
# print(df_)

   Tech_ID  Std_Id                0
0        1       1  111101110100101
1        1       7  101111101101110
2        2       4  100110100110111
3        3       8  110111101111100
```